# Javascript example in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to write a javascipt that will take a large amount values from a text files and will use those values to make a large set of queries to find a filed. for example there are 2000 values given in the text file, then i'm trying to read the values from the file and it will use each value to excute each query. So im not getting the concept how to write it, cause it is not possible to write 2000 queries separately, please help

```
var values = new Array();
$.get('UserFile.txt', function(data){
        values = data.split('\n');
        console.log(value);
    db.students.find(CID:{$in[values]})
    });
```

This is the concept I want to apply, the UserFile.txt got 20000 values and it will use those values to find it. Also it gives "$" is not defined in the shell

Comment: So what are you actually asking for? There is no real information in here in which to base a code example on or either point to what may be the current problem with your approach. Some code of any sort would be required in order to answer this question. Please edit to show at least what you are trying.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it properly, I added the code now, hope it will explain properly

Comment: `$.get` is a jQuery function. If you're trying to run this in the MongoDB shell, jQuery won't be available to you. If you're running this outside the MongoDB shell (something like Node.JS), we'd need to know what library you're using to talk to MongoDB.

Comment: Do you actually have any libraries available to the shell that allows you do do things such as load a file? You would be better off doing this in a proper programming language rather than just doing it in the shell.

Comment: oh didn't realize that but overall is the concept is correct, like parsing the values in an array and then putting the array in the $in condition. Does it make sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is sound provided that you actually have a library that can load the contents of a file for you, so would likely be better suited to another language implementation or something like nodejs if you want JavaScript, as opposed to doing this in the mongo shell.

Aside from that the only issue is your syntax for the use of the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator, which should rather be:

```js
values = filecontent.split('\n'); // Somehow obtained from reading a file

db.students.find({ "CID": { "$in": values } });
```

That is because whatever went into `values` is already a native array to the language and will be passed in as such for an argument to [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) which expects it's argument to be an array.

It probably isn't the best idea to pass in a very large array and your total request must be under the 16MB BSON limit. So you may need to split up those array elements into several queries, but in batch sizes rather than singular, so that is at least better.

I could be wrong, but I don't find it likely you are going to find a library you could load that allows this, you can load native JavaScript as a structure but that would be beside the point.

Use something else as your language implementation and you can get the desired result by following the correct syntax.

Comment: yes finally I got the idea but need to clear something, I'm learning mongodb. So if i'm not wrong you are trying to say that I should use another language rather than javascript! What language you prefer and isn't it possible to write it in javascript and load it in mongo by calling load<>

Comment: @user3515895 Load will only load and evaluate a JavaScript file. If you want to use JavaScript as a language then look at [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/)